# VLOOKUP filling in blank spaces

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup

So honestly I feel really dumb here. I have a very large file that has a lot of blank values where there should have populated a name, and I wanted to use a formula to fill those in. The data that I have is what appears in Columns A and B: A bunch of customer names and corresponding transaction codes (that repeat several times over), but blank spaces in a lot of places where the customer name should be. My attempt to fix this was to try filtering the data to get rid of the blank spaces, and use a VLOOKUP formula off that new table. Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong here? I don't care if it's a VLOOKUP, I just know there's an easier way to fix this that I'm not seeing, but none of the posts I've found fixed my issue...Thanks for any help you can give. [Snapshot of Excel Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qKM3l.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vlookup only performs matching left-to-right: the matching column has to be the first column of the range(D2:D13).

If you have Excel 365, you can use Xlookup:

```
=XLOOKUP(B7,E$2:E$13,D$2:D$13,,0)
```

or if not, you can use Index/Match:

```
=INDEX(D$2:D$13,MATCH(B8,E$2:E$13,0))
```

[image]

It might be more convenient to test for blank cells in column A and fill them in using a separate column if so, eg in C2:

```
=IF(A2="",XLOOKUP(B2,E$2:E$13,D$2:D$13,,0),A2)
```

Comment: That's exactly what I needed, thank you so much! Don't know why I couldn't use my head!